# ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I followed [Connecting GitLab with a Kubernetes cluster | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#adding-an-existing-kubernetes-cluster) and 
[GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/applications.html#gitlab-runner) and now trying to follow [GitLab CI/CD Pipeline Configuration Reference](https://gitlab.regemini.com/help/ci/yaml/README), yet running into following error:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is
>   the docker daemon running?

job:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.10.1 (1f513601)
  on runner-gitlab-runner-5b8d5bf7db-5phqs 3gRXuKPT
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
Using Kubernetes executor with image docker:latest ...
Waiting for pod gitlab-managed-apps/runner-3grxukpt-project-18-concurrent-1m7ttl to be running, status is Pending
Running on runner-3grxukpt-project-18-concurrent-1m7ttl via runner-gitlab-runner-5b8d5bf7db-5phqs...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/X/test/.git/
Fetching changes...
Created fresh repository.
From https://gitlab.X.com/X/test
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
Checking out 72b6895d as master...

Skipping Git submodules setup
$ docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

$ docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Official docker image.
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY

build-master:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
  only:
    - master

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  except:
    - master
```

Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to the daemon docker in a docker image of docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370599/cannot-connect-to-the-daemon-docker-in-a-docker-image-of-docker)

Comment: @mbuechmann I already have `- docker:dind` in `services:` as part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my case I had to add following `variables` into `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
```